# The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type BancoDeDados

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou com problemas ao criar uma classe que criasse e manipulasse o banco de dados! Mas no método `criar()` deu um problema dizendo que

> "The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for
>   the type BancoDeDados".

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para contornar tal problema?! Meu código segue abaixo:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class BancoDeDados {
     private SQLiteDatabase db;
     private String DATABASE_NAME;
     private String TABLE_NAME;
     private String SQL_SELECT_ALL;
     private String SQL_SELECT_ID;
     private String SQL_CREATE;

     public BancoDeDados(SQLiteDatabase db,String DATABASE_NAME,String TABLE_NAME,String SQL_SELECT_ALL,String SQL_SELECT_ID,String SQL_CREATE){
         this.db = db;
         this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
         this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ALL = SQL_SELECT_ALL;
         this.SQL_SELECT_ID = SQL_SELECT_ID;
         this.SQL_CREATE = SQL_CREATE;
     }

     public void criar(){
         this.db = openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
         this.db.execSQL(this.SQL_CREATE);
         this.db.close(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Você não quis dizer `this.db.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);`?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não, mas também tentei dessa forma e não de solucionar meu problema! Encontrei a solução usando `Context`

Answer (score 2):

São dois erros.

O primeiro é que você está tentando chamar um método que não existe na classe `BancoDeDados`. Isso porque `BancoDeDados` precisa ser uma subclasse de `SQLiteDatabase`, ou então conter uma instância (objeto) do tipo `SQLiteDatabase`, como por exemplo o objeto `db`, para assim poder chamar algum dos métodos `openOrCreateDatabase()` disponíveis nessa classe (confira na [documentação de SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) que são três formas de chamar esse método). São duas maneiras de resolver esse erro: declarar `public class BancoDeDados extends SQLiteDatabase` ou então chamar `db.openOrCreateDatabase(...)` no lugar de `openOrCreateDatabase(...)`.

O segundo erro é que, mesmo se você puder chamar o método `openOrCreateDatabase()`, a assinatura desse método está incorreta, isto é, os parâmetros passados a ele não batem com os tipos aceitos pelo método. Você está chamando o método com os tipos `String`, `int` e `null`, sendo que os parâmetros aceitos são de outros tipos.

Uma das assinaturas aceitáveis recebe uma `String`, uma `SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory` e um `DatabaseErrorHandler`. Portanto, se você passar os parâmetros `(String, null, null)` pode ser que funcione. Mas não esqueça de resolver o primeiro erro antes disso.

Comment: Obrigado por apontar os meus "erros"! Mas pra ser sincero eu já sabia todos esses "erros" antes de postá-lo aqui, queria alguma sugestão de como usar o método `openOrCreateDatabase(...) da android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, CursorFactory factory)` que retorna uma variável do tipo `SQLiteDatabase`. Então `1º` a assinatura `NÃO` está errada. `2º: Minha classe NÃO pode extender a classe SQLiteDatabase`, motivo: >The type BancoDeDados cannot subclass the final class SQLiteDatabase

Comment: `3º tinha usado antes também db.openOrCreateDatabase(...), claro com os parâmetros de entrada de forma correta!` Mas por algum motivo não estava resolvendo o meu problema! `SOLUÇÃO: A solução para o meu problema está em Context`, pronto resolvi meu problema!!

Answer (score 1):

O principal motivo de criar essa classe para criar e manipulação de banco de dados é de **reaproveitá-la** e além do mais essa classe NÃO precisou EXTENDS nenhuma outra!

Abaixo Minha Classe depois de resolvido o problema.
`BancoDeDados.java`

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

 public class BancoDeDados {
 private String DATABASE_NAME;
 private int DATABASE_VERSION;
 private String TABLE_NAME;
 private String SQL_SELECT_ALL;
 private String SQL_SELECT_ID;
 private String SQL_CREATE;

 public BancoDeDados(String DATABASE_NAME,int DATABASE_VERSION,String TABLE_NAME,String SQL_SELECT_ALL,String SQL_SELECT_ID,String SQL_CREATE){
     this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
     this.DATABASE_VERSION = DATABASE_VERSION;
     this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
     this.SQL_SELECT_ALL = SQL_SELECT_ALL;
     this.SQL_SELECT_ID = SQL_SELECT_ID;
     this.SQL_CREATE = SQL_CREATE;
 }
 public BancoDeDados(String DATABASE_NAME,int DATABASE_VERSION,String TABLE_NAME,String SQL_SELECT_ALL,String SQL_CREATE){
     this.DATABASE_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;
     this.DATABASE_VERSION = DATABASE_VERSION;
     this.TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME;
     this.SQL_SELECT_ALL = SQL_SELECT_ALL;
     this.SQL_CREATE = SQL_CREATE;
 }

public void onCreate(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db){
     //openOrCreateDatabase --> Cria ou Abre banco de dados
     //(nome.db,permissão (modo), ...)
     // MODE_PRIVATE --> Priva o acesso do banco para somente aplicação
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     db.execSQL(this.SQL_CREATE); //Criando tabela caso não exista!!
     db.close();
 }

public void onUpgrade(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + this.TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(ctx,db);
 }

 public long onWrite(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,String row,ContentValues ctv){
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     long lg = db.insert(this.TABLE_NAME,row,ctv);
     db.close();
     return lg;
 }

 public int onUpdate(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,ContentValues ctv,String row,int id){
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     int x = db.update(this.TABLE_NAME, ctv, row, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
     db.close();
     return x;
 }

 public Cursor onSelecAll(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db){
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(this.SQL_SELECT_ALL, null);
     return cursor;
 }

 public Cursor onSelecId(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,int id){
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_SELECT_ID, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
     return cursor;
 }

 public int onDelete(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db,String row,int id){
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     int x = db.delete(this.TABLE_NAME, row, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
     db.close();
     return x;
 }

 public void onClose(Context ctx,SQLiteDatabase db){
     db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(this.DATABASE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
     db.close();
 }
```

}

E na `Main.java` temos:

```
     import android...
     public class Main extends Activity {

 private SQLiteDatabase db;
 private Context ctx;
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bancodedado.db";
 private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tabela";
 private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
 private static final String SQL_SELECT_ID = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE _id = ?";
 /* SQL de criação do banco de dados. */
 private static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela(" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    "pessoa VARCHAR(30), " 
                    "animal VARCHAR(30))";
 BancoDeDados BD = new BancoDeDados(DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_VERSION,TABLE_NAME,SQL_SELECT_ALL,SQL_SELECT_ID,SQL_CREATE);
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    ctx = getBaseContext(); //Context para usar na classe BancoDeDados
    BD.onCreate(ctx, db); // Criar BD e tabela caso sejam necessários!! 
   /* .... */
 }
}
```